# can i add .h and .cpp files in a c# project?

Tags: c#, c++

I want to add some .h and .cpp files to a C# project to get the C++ functionality in C#. I want to use the code directly without making a dll.

Can i do so? How?

Comment: Why would someone downvote that question? it's a legitimate question for someone starting to develop with .NET and want to use his C++ libraries

Comment: Note. AFAIK C++/CLI doesn't support  C++20 yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you cannot. If the amount of code is small, you can write a C# class and paste pieces of the C++ code into it so that you essentially ported that class into C#. Obviously this won't work if you're using a language feature or library function that is not in C#. Alternatively you need to compile your C++ code into something executable (either a native DLL, ideally C-style flat functions, or a managed assembly) so that you can call it from your C# code.

Answer (score 5):

Even though it may be late I'd like to answer your question as I have had a similar problem.

You can do this via compiling C++ code to netmodule and add the module to CSharp command line.

Long story short. **First way** is the following:

1. Create custom build call for .cpp file, like cl /clr /MD /LN /link /DLL /LTCG /NOASSEMBLY /NOENTRY yourfile.cpp
2. Add produced netmodule to cs compilation

This one is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/texblog/linking-native-c-into-c-applications) in detail.

**Second way** is:

1. Create another C++/CLI project with your code
2. Use [ILMerge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge) to merge C++/CLI project assembly to your C# project DLL

That one is uncovered [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/mixing-languages-in-a-single-assembly-in-visual-studio-seamlessly-with-ilmerge-and-msbuild)

This is an **example of MSBuild setup for csproj for the first way**:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="CppFile1.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="CppFile2.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NetmoduleName>CppCli.netmodule</NetmoduleName>
    <ClOptions>/nologo /clr /LN /I"$(SolutionDir)anotherDir" /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /Od /Gd /MDd </ClOptions>
    <LinkOptions>/LTCG /DLL /NOASSEMBLY /NOENTRY /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /out:$(OutputPath)$(NetmoduleName) another.lib /LIBPATH:"$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)" /LIBPATH:"anotherDir"</LinkOptions>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomCppBuildStep" Inputs="@(ClCompile)" Outputs="$(NetmoduleName)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ClCompileFullName Include="@(ClCompile->'%(fullpath)', ' ')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Compiling cpp: @(ClCompileFullName)" />
    <Exec Command="$(ComSpec) /c &quot;C:\Progra~2\Micros~3.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat amd64 &amp; cl $(ClOptions) @(ClCompileFullName) /link $(LinkOptions) &quot;" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="CustomCppBuildStep" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't.

You'll either have to migrate the code to C# or comiple the C++ code down into a DLL and then call that from C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the code in c++ the best option is to use C++/CLI where you can include .h and .cpp files and reference the compiled dll from your c# project.